# Extern variable seems to have two addresses?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, extern, memory-address

I am working with a library that declares a uint32_t in a .h and defines it in a .c. The program can't read the variable and crashes.

Declaration :

```
extern uint32_t SystemCoreClock;
```

Definition :

```
uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 4000000;
```

Using the variable :

```
uint32_t tickNum=123, *ptr1=NULL, *ptr2=NULL; // added by me to debug
ptr1 = &tickNum;                              // added by me to debug
ptr2 = &SystemCoreClock;                      // added by me to debug
tickNum = SystemCoreClock;                    // added by me to debug
```

Then I check the addresses with gdb.

Execute first 3 lines.

Normal stuff (`ptr1 == &ticknum` and `*ptr1 == ticknum`):

```
(gdb) p &tickNum
$3 = (uint32_t *) 0x20017fdc
(gdb) p ptr1
$4 = (uint32_t *) 0x20017fdc
(gdb) p *ptr1
$5 = 123
```

Now execute the last line of code.

Strange stuff (`ptr2 != &SystemCoreClock` and `*ptr2 != SystemCoreClock`) :

```
(gdb) p &SystemCoreClock
$6 = (uint32_t *) 0x20000004 <SystemCoreClock>
(gdb) p ptr2
$7 = (uint32_t *) 0x681b4b20           // should be 0x20000004, beyond end of memory (see memory map bellow)
(gdb) p SystemCoreClock
$8 = 4000000
(gdb) p *ptr2
$9 = 0                                 // should be 4000000
(gdb) p tickNum 
$10 = 0                                // should be 4000000
```

How can that be ?!

Memory map, my guess from the linker script :

```
0x20000000 - 0x20018000, LENGTH = 96K       RAM
0x10000000 - 0x10008000, LENGTH = 32K       RAM
0x08000000 - 0x08100000, LENGTH = 1024K     FLASH
```

Real linker script :

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 96K
RAM2 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 32K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 1024K
}
```

---

- Target : STM32L4 ARM-CortexM4 MCU
- Host : Linux, Qt Creator, arm-none-eabi-gcc, OpenOCD
- Versions : CubeMX v4.18.0 , STM32L4 package v1.6.0, gcc v5.4.1

Comment: You are probably not exectuing `ptr2 = &SystemCoreClock;`; you need *execute* line on which GDB currently points at. Do "next" and see.

Comment: You can also add extra NOP lines to guarantee the execution of the code lines after line 3.

Comment: Are you really running STM32L4 code directly on an STM32F4? That's liable to be a rich source of problems (e.g. that RAM at 0x10000000 may not even be there on some F4's, for starters). The fact that the debug illusion isn't perfect mostly just implies you're compiling with a reasonable level of optimisation.

Comment: what does the disassembly show?  is it global are you passing it into a function even though it is global (in that case there might be one copy on the stack at one address and then the global at its address)?